# Node.js passport-facebook callback looping

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm using passport-facebook to login my users and i´m getting into undefined loop when facebook calls myt callback. I have read lot of sites and question, even here, but really, i cant find any solution.

Here is the code, I´m going to put it all here, like it were into une single file:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var passport = require('passport-restify');
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: 'APP_ID',
  clientSecret: 'APP_SECRET',
  callbackURL: 'http://192.168.0.13:8080/login/facebook/callback'
  }, function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        //this code never is executed, why?
        return done(null, profile);
  }));

server.use(passport.initialize());

server.get('/login/facebook', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { display: null, scope: ['email']})(req, res, next);
});

server.get('/login/facebook/callback', (req, res, next) => {
        //here is where the loop happends, i´m getting into this and never can go out from here
        passport.authenticate('facebook', function(profile) {
            //I could not execute this
            if (!profile || !profile.id) {
                return res.json(500, 'We had trouble signing you up with Facebook. Please try again or sign-up via email.');
            } else {
                res.json(200, profile);
            }
        })(req, res, next);
});

server.listen(config.port, function () {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

Really, i'm very frustrated, i now, i now, there are thousands of post talking about that... I tried all of them, i'm here anyway...

Thanks.

Comment: Could you showing your serialize / deserialize functions ?

Comment: passport.serializeUser(function (profile, done) {
  done(null, profile);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (profile, done) {
  done(null, profile);
});

Comment: inside the serializeUser try to replace this `done(null, profile)` by this `done(null, profile.id)`

Comment: I got the same result... an infinite loop in the same line. Thanks very much

Comment: Your server running on nginx ?

Comment: No no, i'm just running on restify (express). Here is my package.json (i've avoided what i thinks we dont need this time...)

  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.7",
    "node-fetch": "^1.6.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-google": "^0.3.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth2": "^0.1.6",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-restify": "^1.0.1",
    "restify": "4.1.x",
    "restify-jwt": "^0.4.0"
  },

Comment: I got the same error once time ago this was because my callbackUrl was bad. I set the port :8080 then I removed it because I have a proxy pass on my server and it works but it is not your case apparently. Have you tried to use the old syntax for anonymous functions ? Remove the => as you did on your other functions. `function(req, res, next){`

Comment: I tried what John suggested to me, but the problem is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after a little while. What i've posted was the result of multiple test.

The problem was i was using in a bad way the parhentesis.
Being simplest, I was doing this:

```
server.get('/login/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', (req, res, next) => { /* magic here*/ });
```

So, the callback for next() execution was passed like it was into the authenticate method. This was not because I didn't understand the problem, It was just I didn't realize where the error was.

The correct way should be:

```
server.get('/login/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook'), (req, res, next) => { /* magic here */ });
```

Thanks everybody for cooperating.